# Node not taking id when importing from template

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to set an id on a node from a template but I cant make it work the div does not take the id.

```js
let template = document.getElementById("template-wide-image");
let node = document.importNode(template.content, true);
node.id = "mouhaha";
console.log(node.id); // mouhaha
document.getElementById("article").appendChild(node); // shows on screen as expected
console.log(document.getElementById(node.id)); // null
```

```html
<div id="article"></div>
<template id="template-wide-image">
  <div class="article-wide-image droppable">
    <img src="" alt="Drop image here" class="droppable">
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`node` here is the content of the template, it's not an actual HTML node, it's a [`DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_NODE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) so it can't have an `id`.

But you can apply this id to the first element (the `div` here) contained inside using [`firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild) :

```js
let template = document.getElementById("template-wide-image"),
    node = document.importNode(template.content, true),
    myId = "mouhaha";
    
node.firstElementChild.id = myId;
console.log(node.firstElementChild);

document.getElementById("article").appendChild(node); // shows on screen as expected
console.log(document.getElementById(myId));
```

```html
<div id="article"></div>
<template id="template-wide-image">
  <div class="article-wide-image droppable">
    <img src="" alt="Drop image here" class="droppable">
  </div>
</template>
```